# Accepting a wav audio file over HTTP POST in an Express/Node server

Tags: node.js, audio, curl, express

I'm trying to send an audio file `audio.wav` via cURL to my Express server. I'm using the following cURL request:

```
 curl -X POST --data-binary @"audio.wav" -H "Content-Type: audio/wav" localhost:3000/extract_indicators/audio/darksigma
```

On my server, I use the following line at the top:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

So that I can by default parse the body of the incoming request as JSON. In my appropriate Express routing handler, I have:

```
app.post('/extract_indicators/audio/:user_id', function (req, res) {
  app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'audio/wav' }));
  console.log("RECIEVED AUDIO TO EXTRACT INDICATORS: ", req.body);
  <do stuff with audio and send result back>
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
});
```

My call to `console.log` prints:

```
RECIEVED AUDIO TO EXTRACT INDICATORS:  {}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does `req.body` not contain my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is fixed by using the following declaration (outside of the `app` handler):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'audio/wav', limit: '50mb' }));

app.post('/extract_indicators/audio/:user_id', function (req, res) {
  console.log("RECIEVED AUDIO TO EXTRACT INDICATORS: ", req.body);
  <do stuff with audio and send result back>
});
```

The console output is now:

```
RECIEVED AUDIO TO EXTRACT INDICATORS:  <Buffer 52 49 46 46 54 b0 01 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 80 3e 00 00 00 7d 00 00 02 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 30 b0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... >
```