# Cannot save recorder.js record wav file to node/express backend

Tags: node.js, audio, multipartform-data

I'm having a hard time plugging lines together.

I'm using [videojs-record](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record), here's what I have:

```
recorder.on('finishRecord',  function(){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', recorder.recordedData);
  $http.post('/api/submit_record', formData, { // Using Angular...
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'audio/wav'}
  });
});
```

Then on the server side:

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

app.post('/api/submit_record', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'audio/wav', limit: '1mb' }), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  fs.writeFile('public/myFile.wav', req.body, function(err) {
    console.log('File uploaded', fileName);
    res.write('File saved');
    res.end();
  });
});
```

But my files are not readable at the end...

I know somehow I should have a reference to the `file` key in the `formData` but I haven't found where.

Been reading many examples about this, but nobody found a solution for me...

I just made my backend work with the following curl request as from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756393/accepting-a-wav-audio-file-over-http-post-in-an-express-node-server):

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @"public/sounds/1c0334bff518849e00aadd754b1a94f0.wav" -H "Content-Type: audio/wav" http://192.168.99.100:3000/api/submit_record
```

I really don't mind if the data is sent over `FormData`, in `json`, or `www-encoded`, I'd just like this to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `FormData` instance. That's only for when you're trying to send more than just one thing. Change your client-side request to this:

```
recorder.on('finishRecord',  function(){
  $http.post('/api/submit_record', recorder.recordedData, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'audio/wav'}
  });
});
```

And then you can probably change your server-side code to this:

```
app.post('/api/submit_record', (req, res) => {
  req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('public/myFile.wav'))
    .on('error', (e) => res.status(500).end(e.message))
    .on('close', () => res.end('File saved'))
});
```

Comment: I did not even think of trying this one! Thanks mate!